# Is it bad practise to assume a container value will get automatically created?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Let's say I have a map in C++ with strings as keys and sets of ints as values, and I will be adding the pairs while reading from some source (i.e.: I can't initialize the map within the code because I don't know what keys will be read from source). Would it be bad practise to dynamically add elements to the set while reading, using map["someKey"].insert(someIntValue)?

I mean something like this (not real code, just an example):

```
map<string, set<int>> myMap;
while (reading_from_source(something)){
    string key=obtainKeyFromSource();
    myMap[key].insert(obtainIntFromSource());
}
```

What worries me is that I only said "there will be a map and it will have sets as values" but I never actually created those sets, I just started inserting elements to them.

If this is bad practise, what would be the right way?

Comment: depends what you want, if you want to acces an element in the map and make sure it exists in the map you can use `map::find` instead of `[]`

Answer (score 6):

When you do `myMap[key]`, if the key doesn't exist then the key-data pair will be *created* for you. So the `set` will exists, always.

From [this `std::map::operator[]` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, **performing an insertion if such key does not already exist**.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

So my answer to the question is that it's not bad practice, and it is the right way to do it.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I've been relying on. But would it be ok to assume this will be the case always (as in standard C++ and not a specific compiler). With a simpler map containing just ints as its values, would it be ok then to start using those ints without initializing them first? As in `myMap[someKey]++`

Comment: @Anarelle It's a little hard to decipher from the reference (at least from after the C++11 standard) but it basically means that the data is default- or value-initialized, and for a primitive type like `int` value-initialization is the same as zero-initialization which means the `int` data will be initialized to zero.

Comment: The question already assumes this behavior. This answer is redundant and does not answer the question.